# Recommendation for Rich Client Platform for CRUD application

Tags: java, netbeans, air, eclipse-rcp

I will develop a desktop application for asset tracking. I am considering Eclipse RCP and Netbeans Platform. I have only Swing experience but SWT will not be a problem for me. One more option is developing with flex on Adobe Air. I know flex but no air experience (they are much similar)

- Speed which one is faster to develop as a RAD
- Learning curve
- Component (like generating charts, reports)

What components do you recommend? I looked a bit and found iReport and BIRT so far.

What do you recommend? Any other option is also welcome.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The platforms you've laid out are pretty heavy weight.  For a lightweight option, you might want to consider [bsaf](http://kenai.com/projects/bsaf).  For a simple application, it'll get you up and running very quickly.

If you are doing CRUD, I recommend that you consider [MiGLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) as a layout manager for your forms (it's insanely easy to lay out forms with MiG).  Also read up on Marin Fowler's discussion of the PresentationModel approach to GUI development.  We've been using it for the past couple of years and it has had significant impact on the simplicity of our code.  We use [BBB](http://kenai.com/projects/betterbeansbinding/pages/Home) for a binding framework with [PresentationModel](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html), and it's a dream to develop new panels.

FWIW - the bsaf project is currently caught up in the whole kenai/java.net/oracle fiasco.  The official code repository is still on Kenai, and will be migrating to java.net at some point in the future.  But it has an active development base, and isn't in danger of going away.

Answer (score 1):

Swing would be the best choice, because you have experience with it.
[SwingX](https://swingx.dev.java.net/) is a good set of extra components.

Eclipse RCP is also a good option. Adobe Air is something I would recommend against - the last time I used Flex (an year ago) it was not stable enough (personal opinion, but developing flex/air with Java experience is painful)